# Accessing JSON object in conditional statement

Tags: android, json

For developing an android application I need to check whether the value inside json object is empty or not.How can I do that? Parameters passed are username,password

```
private void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
     prgDialog.show();
     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     client.get("url for restful web service", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
     {
         public void onSuccess(String response){
                             prgDialog.hide();

                             try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    if(obj.length()==1){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " NOT a valid User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String content){
             prgDialog.hide();
             if(statusCode == 404){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } 
             else if(statusCode == 500){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }
     } );
```

}

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried ? What is your actual JSON response?

Comment: @ANN ... stackoverflow help them...who help themselves....

Comment: ok ..now fine... :-) .... that means... obj.length()==1 condition is set to true always.... try to log the the value or debug...or i think you better use obj.has(String value)

Comment: you can check for length/size in case of JSONArray ...no for JSONObject

Comment: :-) i have already tried has().i would like to know what should be the parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
then you should use this:

if(obj != null){

JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("validate")
if(data.length()==1){
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject user = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = user.getString("id").toString()
                    String class = user.getString("class").toString()
                    String name = user.getString("name").toString()

                   Log.i("user Details ", "id = "+id+" class = "+class+" name = "+name);

                }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " NOT a valid User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
    }else{
    Log.e("obj is null", "No date on JSON");
    }



      **try this in your try Block**
```

Comment: still exception is handled

Comment: what will be the value inside jobj??

Comment: value of jObj will be : {
"data":"your data"
}

Comment: my json is {"validate":[{"id":1,"class":3,"name":xyz}]}

Comment: so replace status with validate and then start a for loop to get these values

Comment: i don't want to display this values.i just want to display whether its a valid user or not. i have tried by replacing status with validate.but still exception is handled

Comment: create one new variable: JSONArray data;

Comment: why should we create jsonarray varaible? we are using jsonobject

Comment: if possible could u please explain it further by showing where should i use jsonarray variable

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check whether the value inside json object is empty or
>   not.How can I do that?

JSONObject has tow methods :

[JSONObejct.has(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29):

*Return true if requested key is found in current json object*

[JSONObejct.isNull(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29) :

*Return `true` if requested key not found in json object and if key found but value is NULL*